# solving linear equations using matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables, for-loop, matrix

my script creates a matrix and 2 vectors using several 'for' loops and as an example they are returned as follows:

```
K =

  1.0e+006 *

    1.2409    0.6250    0.8153    0.1250
    0.6250    3.6591   -0.1250    3.5375
    0.8153   -0.1250    1.2409   -0.6250
    0.1250    3.5375   -0.6250    3.6591

F =

  1.0e+006 *

    0.1733
    1.3533
   -0.1066
    1.3371

U =

 u3
 v3
 u4
 v4
```

As can be seen, the `'U'` vector is a set of variables and I need to solve `'K*U=F'` for variables contained in `'U'`.

When I try to do that using `linsolve` or `solve` I get unexpected results and a message that the inverse of my matrix is close to singular.

HOWEVER, when I make another script and put in the SAME matrix and vectors BY HANDS it all works fine and I can't figure out what's wrong.

Is that somehow related to the way MATLAB stores matrices created by loop functions and I need to change the state of the matrix to something after the loop?

Also, when I put the matrix by hands it displays it without the `1.0e+006` multiplier in front of it:

```
K11 =

     1240900      625000      815300      125000
      625000     3659100     -125000     3537500
      815300     -125000     1240900     -625000
      125000     3537500     -625000     3659100
```

can that be related??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to print matrix generated by loop in 'format long' mode. It seems your 'manual' matrix is rounded and real matrix is near singular.

Comment: As Danil said, your matrix when rounded to 4dp is non singular, but somewhat poorly scaled, with a condition number about 5E5. It may have actually been singular before it was rounded. We need to see actual matrix generated in your "loop" to a higher number of decimal points to confirm this. Enter the instruction **format long** (enter) and then display the matrix.

Comment: `K11 =`

  `1.0e+006 *`

   `[1.240863111684165   0.625000000000000   0.815316663596734   0.125000000000000;
   0.625000000000000   3.659106956468349  -0.125000000000000   3.537522257014797;
   0.815316663596734  -0.125000000000000   1.240863111684165  -0.625000000000000;
   0.125000000000000   3.537522257014797  -0.625000000000000   3.659106956468349]`

Comment: don't think rounding up would change the condition that much

Comment: rcond(K)=1.6699e-006 - for rounded matrix, rcond(K)=2.6514e-017 - for initial matrix, you think that's what causing the problem?

Comment: Yes that's your problem for sure, the original matrix is singular at the level of the machine precision. The condition number I get here as about 7E16. BTW Vitaly, the figures you quote are *reciprocal* condition. It gives basically the same information though, either a big number for condition or a small (near zero) number for reciprocal condition means your matrix is singular or poorly scaled.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have a problem then... How to tell matlab to round up the numbers so that they look as I wrote above?

Comment: No your problem is deeper than that. If you take a singular matrix and make it non-singular just by rounding (or random perturbations) then your result may be meaningless.

Comment: the result is for a university project and I already have 367 lines of code, I simply don't want to check every line to see what I've done wrong... So I just want to round up the numbers cause they give pretty much realistic results...

Comment: Stuart is right, if rounding significantly changes your results, it means the introduction of arbitrary errors. It looks like the problem lies at least one step before this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the previous discussion it's clear that your matrix is singular. This means that your equations are not linearly independent. When this happens there are two possibilities. Your system may be **inconsistent** (over-constrained), in which case **no** solutions exist. Or alternatively, it can also mean that your equations are under-constrained, in which case there is an infinite **set** of solutions.

To determine which case it is you can use **rref** to get the "row reduce echelon form" of the matrix. Do this as follows:

```
 KF = [K,F]
 rref(KF)
```

If the last row goes entirely to zeros then you're under-constrained and can extract a solution set (but not a unique solution) from your reduced matrix.

In this case however I get a row of [0 0 0 0 1], which makes the system over-constrained and hence without any solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try the backslash operator:

```
U = K\F
```

See [this reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html).

Comment: the main question here is why MATLAB gives me different values if I create a matrix using loop functions compared to the same matrix but put in by hands